# Laravel form with two buttons get value of clicked button on submit

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view with two buttons, when clicking on one of the two buttons I want to receive the value of that button.

```
<form action="{{ url('selectMode') }}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <button class="card mt-3"><i class="fas fa-laptop my-pr"></i>Computer<label>
            <input hidden name="mode" value="1">
        </label></button>
    <br>
    <button class="card-disabled mt-3"><i class="fas fa-user my-pr"></i>Person<label>
            <input hidden name="mode" value="2">
        </label></button>
</form>
```

This is the code I have so far. When dumping the request in the controller the value is always '2'. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: If you have two inputs with the same name (in this case `name="mode"`), the "latest" one (i.e. the one lowest on the page) will take precedence when the form is submitted. You need some logic to disable the other input when you click the button (remove the name, add `disabled`, etc)

Comment: I think you should use AJAX here. put onclick() event on the button and set the request parameter with which button is clicked and submit using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Blade file:

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="status" value="approve">Approve</button>
    <button type="submit" name="status" value="decline">Decline</button>
    <button type="submit" name="status" value="reject">Reject</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    switch ($request->input('status')) {
        case 'approve':
            // Redirect to approve page
            break;

        case 'decline':
            // Redirect to decline page
            break;

        case 'reject':
            // Redirect to reject page
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a value a button

```html
<button type="input" value="value">
```

or input a type button

```html
<input type="button" value="value">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button